# Unable to apply function right after instanctiation of a DateTime PhP object

Tags: php, datetime, instantiation

I try to extract the year of a string date using [`DateTime::`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

I do not understand why the following instantiation of DateTime throws an error :

```
$myDate = "2015-09-10";

$year_myDate = new DateTime($myDate)->format("Y");
```

knowing that this one actually works :

```
$myDate = "2015-09-10";

$dateTime_myDate = new DateTime($myDate);

$year_myDate = $dateTime_myDate->format("Y");
```

Would not the object return an instance of itself ? So why cannot we use a method of this class right after instantiation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, you just have to warp your instantiation into parentheses, e.g.

```
$year_myDate = (new DateTime($myDate))->format("Y");
               ↑                     ↑
```

**Note:**

- This works with [PHP >= 5.4 dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-101)
- `$year_myDate`, won't hold an instance of `DateTime`, just a string (return from `DateTime::format()`)

Comment: This is exactly what I need, It does not matter holding an object of DateTime in my case, I just need the result.

Comment: @Zeratops You're welcome. (Just wanted to make it clear :)